# WPF SaveFileDialog that permits selection of folder, not just file

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

I need a control like `SaveFileDialog` that lets me choose a ***directory*** instead of a file. It should also let me specify the directory by pasting text. SaveFileDialog does not allow this.

I have tried `FolderBrowserDialog`, but it does not meet my requirements because it does not support pasting the directory path as text. Some of the directory I'm working with may be nested 10 levels or more, so being forced to navigate via point-and-click is not enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FolderBrowserDialog` itself may not support this, but it's a thin wrapper around a shell function that does support it. The [`SHBrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx) function's [`BROWSEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205(v=vs.85).aspx) parameter has a flag `BIF_EDITBOX` that does what you want.

You could choose to use `SHBrowseForFolder` directly, or you could use a different pre-made managed wrapper around it, such as [`FolderBrowserDialogEx`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159352/FolderBrowserDialogEx-A-C-customization-of-FolderB).

Answer (score 2):

AFAK there is  no  built-in control in windows for doing such thing. You have do it yourself using a treeview control and iterating through all your nested folders

here [**`A Simple WPF Explorer Tree`**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21248/A-Simple-WPF-Explorer-Tree) you can find an example on how you  can do this