# Get Handler to SaveFileDialog opened by Application

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

I am trying to get the handler to a SaveFileDialog which is opened by a button click of my WPF app. All the examples that I could find in the net actually creates one , but I need to handle one which is already opened. How do I do that?
The below code always creates a new SaveFileDialog

```
        dlg.DefaultExt = "pdf"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "PDF File (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*"; // Filter files by extension
        dlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Reema.Sinha\\Downloads";
        Manager.Current.DialogMonitor.AddDialog(dlg);
        DownloadSaveButton.Click();
        DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: If I got you right, You mean something like if you hit cancel than it should pop up a message box asking for confirmation.. And if clicked save than it should ask for something else...?

Comment: Nope.I hit the download button,automatically a SaveFileDialog opens up and I need a handler to it to set the path name and then save the file as a pdf.

Answer (score -1):

I guess `OpenFileDialog` can also do the trick. But I will prefer [SaveFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) only. I tried this and hope it works for you also:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.DefaultExt = "pdf"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "PDF File (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*"; // Filter files by extension
    dlg.FilterIndex = 2;
    dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Reema.Sinha\\Downloads";
    Manager.Current.DialogMonitor.AddDialog(dlg);
    DownloadSaveButton.Click();

   Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();  // Show save file dialog box

  if (result == true)
  {
    // Save document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Use `FolderBrowserDialog`. Then after you show the dialog to the user, you can do dlg.SelectedPath.

Hopefully these posts are helpfull to you.

[SaveFileDialog that permits selection of folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695513/wpf-savefiledialog-that-permits-selection-of-folder-not-just-file)

[WPF select folder dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007882/select-folder-dialog-wpf)

[Open directory dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922204/open-directory-dialog)

Comment: i had tried this before, but the issue is with : Manager.Current.DialogMonitor.AddDialog(dlg);
dlg has to implement IDialog, but SaveDialog is no way connected to IDialog, and hence Conversion is not possible here.

Comment: I found the SaveAsDialog and it works just fine. Thanks anyways for the help.

Comment: Great.:) upload the answer. It would be helpful to others.